# Ionic 4 Network Interface Returning 0.0.0.0 for IP Address. How to return actual IP address?

Tags: ios, xcode, ip-address, ionic4, network-interface

I've installed the network interface ionic 4 plugin. Configured it and cross referenced several docs to ensure it has been configured appropriately. I'm not receiving any errors. However, the IP address returned from the function is always "0.0.0.0" Surely this cannot be my actual IP address.

Using Ionic 4 with Angular 7

Xcode Capabilities:

Wifi Information -> On

Network Extensions -> On

```
this.networkInterface.getWiFiIPAddress().then(data =>{
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});

this.networkInterface.getCarrierIPAddress().then(data =>{
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Response

```
{
  ip: "0.0.0.0",
  subnet: "0.0.0.0"
}
```

Google: what's my ip

```
2600:***:*:***::1c
```

Anybody else experiencing issues obtaining IP addresses in Ionic4? Or know of a better method?

Comment: It looks like you have an ipv6 address and that plugin doesn't work with ipv6. If you are on a pure ipv6 network then your ipv4 address could indeed be 0.0.0.0

Comment: Without support for ipv6, how is one supposed to obtain the IP? Do you know of another extension? Method?